# How does a game developer get feedback from gamers (not developers) or start a forum community without paying for advertising or hiring Q&A teams?

Tags: game-design, social, community-management

I am familiar with a lot of game developer forums, but I'd assume this is much less likely to attract more casual commentators. I also fear that feedback from a gamer's perspective would often be tainted by their game dev perspective.

For example, if I were making a RTS game and wanted to get feedback from "The RTS gamers" where would I go? Is there a general idea of what type of website or forum to go to?
Do you go to specific game websites, to try to "steal" attention? Would this not equate to spam or inappropriate posting? What is considered appropriate and inappropriate?

I am not asking for specifics. I am asking how one "starts a community", or how one "gets feedback from gamers" without resorting to spamming forums or 'advertising' just to see what sticks. What TYPE OF PLACE does one go? Are there already sites designed for this purpose?

I tried going to what was once a very popular forum for feedback from what I believed was a niche hardcore group of gamers in the genre, but its popularity seemed to have died significantly; Leaving only trolls and very young teenagers. The resulting feedback was quite disappointing, mainly for how little feedback it resulted. Many years ago, feedback would flood in by the hundreds so quickly.

Without this website, I am at a loss as to where to go to see what people think of ideas, gather feedback from a gamer's perspective (not a developer's perspective), or where to pull from to start my own site's forum. I am out of ideas of what to do, short of going to various game forums to post in the off-topic sections there.

Comment: To be more specific, I tried going to a forum which used to be a very popular forum for a specific genre. The most popular area of discussion was also the forum where anything can be posted about the genre. I could post any ideas, poll for what people thought, or even discuss specific game features. Unfortunately, this site is now a ghost town. I do not want to go to game developer forums, or specific game sites. I loved how the site was genre-specific, and attracted all types of gamers in said genre.

Comment: Reddit is generally very good for this try /r/Gamedev /r/indiegaming or perhaps /r/RTS (if it exists) to start your own forum all you need is a hosting provider and a domain, then genreally they have tools that allow you to setup PHPBB or similar automatically

Answer (score 3):

> What TYPE OF PLACE does one go?

**Forums or social media sites**. There are already sites designed for that purpose.

The type of places you want to go are the ones where these gamers are. Search the web for similar indie RTS games. Find out where people are talking about those games and start with that community. Don't spam. Just partake in the discussions, and inject your own questions when appropriate.

Without paying for anything your options are limited. But, if you're allowing people to play your game for free, you'll likely get feedback from those willing to play. Ensure the players have a place to respond, and ask them to share their thoughts. There are a number of free blogging sites, a Facebook page, Twitter, etc.