# How do I start the process of looking for playtesters for an iOS game?

Tags: user-experience, playtesting

How does an independent developer typically go about finding a group of people to playtest their iOS game in 2013?

Is it through Reddit? College campuses? Steam Forums?

For example my game is targeted at males, ages 25-33 and the initial test I want to do on an iPad.

Comment: Also, see my answer here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/64148/7191

Comment: Right, I should've searched for beta testers instead of playtesters